# How do I delete many (but not all) Chrome/Google Account stored website passwords at once?

Tags: google-chrome, password-management, google-accounts

I've seen many recipes to delete ALL Google passwords, but I do not want to remove all, just a big bunch of them!  Is this possible?

Some workaround, like backing up to a local file, delete all from cloud, edit local file and re-upload it would be just as good...

Answer (score 12):

Many people voted down my question, so I decided to research a little bit more and apparently I found some way to do what I needed.  The answer is not trivial, needs some work.

- First, enable importing/exporting passwords to a file.  On older chromes you need to first set a experimental flag: [chrome://flags/#password-import-export](http://chrome://flags/#password-import-export). On newer ones, apparently, exporting is now default, but you need to enable import at [chrome://flags/#PasswordImport](http://chrome://flags/#PasswordImport).  After changing, restart your browser.

If I have know this was possible before, I would not had asked, but have I told that I've been searching for this for a long time?

- Export your passwords to a file: Go to `Settings/Passwords`, click the 3 dots right off "Saved passwords" headline and export!

This will create a CSV file.  Edit as you wish.

- Now, delete all Google Password.  You can do it at `Settings/Advanced/Clear Browsing Data`.  Select `Advanced`, `Passwords and other sign-in data`, and `Clear Data`.
- You may now want to go to https://passwords.google.com/dashboard to check if it is empty.
- Finally, import the edited file.  Go again to `Settings/Passwords`, click the 3 dots right off "Saved passwords" headline and import!
- If you go to https://passwords.google.com/dashboard to check, you may find that it is listing less passwords than there were in the CSV file.  I think it may be because Google counts "Groups of sites", not only "Sites".  For example, https://facebook.com/ is counted as the same as https://www.facebook.com/.

Hope this helps others.

Comment: Works perfectly. Besides this option it seems it's also possible to import / export passwords in your Google account directly.

Comment: Right now, Chrome removes the colon from the `chrome://flags/#password-import-export` and `chrome://flags/#PasswordImport` jumplinks, and in actual fact all password  import and export flags are also absent. It so happens Flags are [temporary](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/tags/77.0.3865.36/docs/flag_expiry.md#Do-Not-Depend-On-Flags).